# iPython shell does not indent

Tags: python, django, indentation

In Django, python manage.py shell, indentation does not work.

This is my code.

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...:
Display all 319 possibilities? (y or n)
...:
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) you should be doing

```
django-admin.py shell -i ipython
django-admin.py shell --interface ipython
```